# Problema con consulta mysql al momento de obtener calificaciones y promedios

Tags: mysql

tengo una consulta que debe calcular los promedios de alumnos según el id de la materia, el periodo y el año, de momento está así:

```
SELECT calificaciones.id_materia,
       Round(Avg (calificaciones.calificacion), 2) AS promedio,
       materias.id,
       materias.nombre_materia,
       CASE
         WHEN Round(Avg (calificaciones.calificacion), 2) = '10.0' THEN 'AU'
         WHEN Round(Avg (calificaciones.calificacion), 2) >= '9.0'
              AND Round(Avg (calificaciones.calificacion), 2) < '10.0' THEN 'DE'
         WHEN Round(Avg (calificaciones.calificacion), 2) >= '8.0'
              AND Round(Avg (calificaciones.calificacion), 2) < '9.0' THEN 'SA'
         ELSE 'NA'
       end                                         AS 'EscalaA',
       IF (calificaciones.calificacion < '8.0', 'Materia sin aprobar',
       'Materia aprobada')                         AS estado
FROM   calificaciones
       INNER JOIN materias
               ON calificaciones.id_materia = materias.id
WHERE  calificaciones.calificacion_matricula = '179170'
       AND calificaciones.periodo = '1'
       AND calificaciones.año = '2022'
GROUP  BY calificaciones.id_materia ASC
```

El problema que encuentro es que si un alumno, por ejemplo de la materia con id=1 tuvo en la unidad 1 un 10.0 y en la unidad 2 un 6.2, como se ve a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el `estado` debería ser "**Materia sin aprobar**" porque tiene unidades que no ha aprobado, pero entiendo que como la consulta encuentra una calificación 10.0 en la unidad 1 para ese id de materia pues no se cumple la condición del `if`.
El resultado fallido es el siguiente, donde ***Matemáticas*** corresponde al id_materia = 1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado de varias formas pero no lo consigo. Así mismo no sé si es posible que en los casos como este donde se tengan unidades sin aprobar (con una calificación menor al 8.0) en lugar de calcular el promedio la `EscalaA` sea directamente 'NA', y que solo en los casos donde todas las unidades de un id de materia estén aprobadas (con una calificación >= 8.0) calcule el promedio. Agradezco sus respuestas y comentarios.

Comment: Pero si la consulta está bien, si es MENOR a 8.0 entonces es desaprobada y tu vista muestra que es 8.10 (MAYOR a 8.0) por tanto es materia aprobada. ¿Dónde está el error? en todo caso el IF no debería evaluar a la calificación sino al promedio.

Comment: Pero es 8.10 porque  es el promedio de la materia, pero en realidad tiene un 10 y un 6.2, ósea tiene una calificación reprobatoria (menor a 8.0). Lo que quiero y no he podido hacer es que todas las calificaciones tienen que ser aprobatorias, independientemente del promedio, para que sea materia aprobada, de lo contrario debería ser materia sin aprobar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que necesitas imaginarte lo que le estás pidiendo a la BBDD.

#### Marco Teórico

En una consulta con agrupación tendrás algunas columnas cuyo valor se expone directamente , y son el criterio de agrupación, ej

```
   -- Se usa el valor del campo y se agrupa por ese valor
   SELECT id_materia 
       ...
   GROUP BY id_materia
```

Lo que arroje esa consulta no puede tener más de un registro por cada `id_materia`, porque si así fuera correspondería agruparlos.

Las columnas cuyo valor es **función de un campo de agrupación** necesariamente se pueden consolidar en un mismo registro.

```
  -- hay sólo un promedio por materia, así que todo está OK
  round(AVG (cf.calificacion),2) AS promedio
```

Tampoco hay problema en usar combinaciones de agregados, dado que la combinación de dos funciones sigue siendo una función. Por ej:

```
  -- por transitividad el campo sigue dependiendo de la misma materia
  AVG (cf.calificacion)/COUNT(*) AS promedio
```

¿Qué pasa cuando un campo no es criterio de agrupación y tampoco es función de éstos? Dependiendo de la configuración del motor, lo que formalmente es incorrecto se pasará por alto. En muchos casos es inofensivo. Por ejemplo  `nombre_materia` tiene relación 1:1 con `id_materia`. Pero hay casos donde no es inofensivo, cuando la tolerancia pasa por alto una omisión que genera un resultado inconsistente.

```
  IF (calificacion < '8.0', 'Materia sin aprobar', 'Materia aprobada')                         AS estado
```

Este campo no es agregado, no es función de `id_materia` y no es un campo de agrupación. A simple vista, generaría dos registros por cada materia, y la BBDD descartará silenciosamente el segundo porque -con la mejor intención- procura devolver sólo un registro para cada materia.

Cuando se configura el cliente de BBDD en modo estricto, en cambio, la omisión anterior se considera un error.

> Expression #6 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
> nonaggregated column 'calificaciones.calificacion' which **is not
> functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause**; this is
> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

#### Solución Propuesta

Tienes dos opciones. Añadir la calificación a los criterios de agrupación (lo cual no tiene sentido) o replantearte lo que quieres calcular. Y aquí viene lo medular:

**¿La regla es que, para aprobar, no se puede tener calificación bajo 8 en ninguna unidad?** entonces **usa la calificación mínima, que sí es un agregado.**

```
  IF (MIN(calificaciones.calificacion) < 8,'Reprobado', 'Aprobado') AS estado
```

Adicionalmente, aunque no es relevante para el resultado, es bueno "podar" la lógica irrelevante, porque no aporta y sólo te confunde. En tu
caso:

- el redondeo no aporta nada en tu `CASE...WHEN...END`.
- no hay razón para comparar floats con strings.
- la comprobación `WHEN x >= 9 AND x<10...`  puede prescindir de `x<10`, porque si no entró en el primer `WHEN` entonces es de perogrullo.
- yo además quitaría `id`, que es redundante.

La consulta quedaría:

```
SELECT id_materia,
       round(AVG (cf.calificacion),2) AS promedio,
       nombre_materia,
        CASE
            WHEN  AVG(cf.calificacion) >= 10 THEN 'AU'
            WHEN  AVG(cf.calificacion) >= 9  THEN 'DE'
            WHEN  AVG(cf.calificacion) >= 8  THEN 'SA'
            ELSE 'NA'
    END AS 'escala',
    IF (MIN(cf.calificacion) < 8,'Reprobado', 'Aprobado') AS estado
FROM calificaciones  cf
    INNER JOIN materias ON cf.id_materia = materias.id 
WHERE cf.matricula = '179170' 
    AND cf.periodo = '1' 
    AND cf.año = '2022' 
GROUP BY cf.id_materia,cf.nombre_materia ASC
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de revisar y ayudarme a resolver mi problema, la solución que indicas funciona a la perfección y los detalles que señalas así como la explicación me han apoyado bastante, ya que no lograba aterrizar por completo la lógica de mi consulta para obtener el resultado deseado, muchísimas gracias.